# How do write a regular expression for one expression?

Tags: python

I would like to extract from one file all sentences that start with `info clockdritf [syncCLK_predict]: predict_part_corr`
I would like just to display all values in that sentences:

```
info clockdritf [syncCLK_predict]: predict_part_corr -1
info clockdritf [syncCLK_predict]: predict_part_corr  5
info clockdritf [syncCLK_predict]: predict_part_corr  8
info clockdritf [syncCLK_predict]: predict_part_corr -7
info clockdritf [syncCLK_predict]: predict_part_corr 15
```

This is my functions, but I does not give me any results:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
plt.style.use('ggplot')
from collections import OrderedDict
from pylab import *
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('ggplot')
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_style('whitegrid')

#info clockdritf [syncCLK_predict]: predict_part_correction -1

try:
    import uncertainties.unumpy as unp
    import uncertainties as unc
except:
    import pip

    pip.main(['install', 'uncertainties'])
    import uncertainties.unumpy as unp
    import uncertainties as unc

Synchronization_Signals_Counter= OrderedDict ({
    'clkpredict':r'info\sclockdritf\s[syncCLK_predict]:\spredict_part_corr\s+([0-9]+)'
})

def Extract_List_Data_Info_Based_On_Regular_Expression(Log_File, re_key):
    # print(re_key)
    re_value = Synchronization_Signals_Counter[re_key]
    fsrc = open(Log_File, 'r')
    buff = fsrc.read()
    list_info = re.findall(re_value, buff)
    print(list_info)
    list_info[0]= ('clkpredict')
    return(list_info)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Log_File='/home/ptl/Simulations/Results.log'

    for re_key in Synchronization_Signals_Counter.keys():
        print(re_key)
        list_info=Extract_List_Data_Info_Based_On_Regular_Expression(Log_File, re_key)
        print(list_info)
```

The obtained results:

```
clkpredict
[]
list_info[0]= ('clkpredict')
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[int(line.split("info clockdritf [syncCLK_predict]: predict_part_corr")[-1]) for line in open("_your_file_path_here_", 'r').readlines()]
```

Comment: thank you very much for you help. But I would like to display only the value.  I would like then to plot it. For that, I have employed the regular expression. The result of your suggestion gives me all the line.

Comment: does this help?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a regular expression you could use the `rsplit()` method to split a string into a list, starting from the right:

```
values = []
with open("log.txt") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        values.append(int(line.rstrip().rsplit(" ", 1)[1]))
```